# Move navbar top position -1px every pixel you scroll up until 20px

Tags: jquery

I have the following:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"></div>
<span></span>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    border:1px solid grey;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    position:fixed;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    height:2000px;
    width:10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var toppos = '-'+pos+'px';
    $("#test").css({'top' : toppos});
    $('#test').stop().animate({
        top: (pos >=20?20:pos)
    }, 0);
});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arnt0ynh/4/)

Basically, for every scroll 1px I want to set the #test top position to negative (amount of pixels scrolled).

So scroll 1px = top: -1px; and so on... up until it reaches 20px.

It is kind of working but it seems in my code it is ignoring the negative value I have set?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should workd:

```
$('#test').stop().animate({
    top: (pos >=20?20:-pos)
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, just a slight amend and it's working: `top: (pos >=20?-20:-pos)`